# Operator $arrayElemAt in aggregation with Mongo < 3.2

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using the **aggregation** framework in Mongo,

How can I achieve the same result in **Mongo < 3.2**  as in **Mongo 3.2** with the operation **$arrayElemAt**?

**Example in Mongo 3.2**

*Collection*

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "dave123", favorites: [ "chocolate", "cake", "butter", "apples" ] }
```

*Query*

```
db.users.aggregate([
   {
     $project:
      {
         name: 1,
         first: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$favorites", 0 ] },
         last: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$favorites", -1 ] }
      }
   }
])
```

It works fine

But, I have been forced to used Mongo 3.0 so I can't use this operator, which is ideal for what I want to do

Is there any way to accessing an element of an array by index with something like...

**Mongo 3.0**

*Collection*

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "dave123", favorites: [ "chocolate", "cake", "butter", "apples" ] }
```

*Query*

```
db.users.aggregate([
   {
     $project:
      {
         name: 1,
         first: { "$favorites.0" },
         last:  { "$favorites.1" }
      }
   }
])
```

I tried and it doesn't work, it gives me an empty array.

However, when they are properties rather than indexes it is able to retrieve the values

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to `$unwind`, `$group` and use the `$first` and `$last` operators like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$favorites" },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "first": { "$first": "$favorites" },
        "last": { "$last": "$favorites" }
    }}
])
```

Or two different queries if `$unwind` is expensive

```
var first = db.collection.find({}, {"favorites": { $slice: 1}})
var last = db.collection.find({}, {"favorites": { $slice: -1}})
```